# MySQL&PHP - Invisible data? Wut?

Tags: php, mysql

I´am trying to insert values into my MySQL from a form but it results in a white blank columns and nothing else in the table.

The first is manually inserted from SQL console:

[image]

My code:

```
<?php
$servername = "mysql1.000webhost.com";
$username = "a5287585_login";
$password = "********";
$dbname = "a5287585_login";
$nickname = $_POST['nickname'];
$pass = $_POST['password'];

// Vytvorenie pripojenia
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Kontrola pripojenia
if ($conn->connect_error) 
{
   die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
echo "Connected successfully ";

// Vloženie dát (Nick,ecc..)
$sql = "INSERT INTO UserDB (Name, Password) VALUES ('$nickname', '$pass')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

Thank you for every help.

*EDIT* Adding form

```
    <body background="IMG/login/bg.png" >
        <form method="POST" action="login.php">
        <center>
            <input type="image" name="submit" src="IMG/login/userimg.png" border="0" alt="Submit" id="button" />
        </center>
        <center>
            <p id="wcome">Welcome</p>
        </center>
        <center>    
            <div id="form"> 
                    <input id="nick" type="text" name="nickname" placeholder="   Nickname" />
                        <br>
                    <input id="pass" type="password" name="password" placeholder="    Password" />
                </form>
        </center>
            </div>
```

Comment: probably because your POST arrays are empty, who knows. You didn't post it. check for `empty()`'ness and alter your columns to not accept NULL/empty values.

Comment: Debugging: try to check your query before execution. echo $sql = "INSERT INTO UserDB (Name, Password) VALUES ('$nickname', '$pass')";exit;      check the result of this query and share or run through console.

Comment: Have you checked if the $_POST is fulfilled with da data? Also you should define your table columns not null.

Comment: Please post your form as well. As there might be issues with the form fields as well. Also try printing the post values as `print_r($_POST)`

Comment: are you using the form/PHP/SQL on the same page?

Comment: I´m using form and PHP&MySQL on the same page.

Comment: @Jediah It's been well over 12 mins now, that I've posted an answer below. That should work. If it still doesn't check for errors with error reporting. That will tell you what's happening or not.

Comment: I fear that you're not showing us your full/real codes here. Your site's form login PHP page is `<form method="POST" action="login.php">` and I get a 404. So you need to fix that. I get redirected to http://error404.000webhost.com/? - that is LOGIN code, not for an INSERT. So, again, you need to use the right page/codes.

Comment: also, your HTML markup is incorrect (in the link you gave me below) and contains many errors. You have to fix that. Look at the HTML source (in Firefox), you will see many errors in red. Check for errors and look at the developer's console. There isn't much else I can do for you here, sorry. What I posted as an answer below, is good/valid code. Your question/code does not support the question/problem you are having.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *"are you using the form/PHP/SQL on the same page? – Fred -ii- 8 mins ago"*
>   *"I´m using form and PHP&MySQL on the same page. – Jediah 2 mins ago"*

You're using your entire code inside the same page and is entering empty data immediately as the page is loaded.

You need to use conditional statements for it and checking if the POST arrays are not [empty](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php).

I.e.

```
if(!empty($_POST['nickname']) && !empty($_POST['password']) )
{ execute the insert and/or place your variables/POST arrays here }
```

**Edit** (example rewrite)

First, remove the following from where you have it now, and placed inside the conditional statements.

```
$nickname = $_POST['nickname'];
$pass = $_POST['password'];
```

and use:

```
if(!empty($_POST['nickname']) && !empty($_POST['password']) )
{

   $nickname = $_POST['nickname'];
   $pass = $_POST['password'];

   $sql = "INSERT INTO UserDB (Name, Password) VALUES ('$nickname', '$pass')";

       if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "New record created successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }

}
```

Plus, it would be beneficial if you were to ALTER your columns in order not to accept NULL/Empty values.

Then using error handling on the query.

Now, if your data contains characters that MySQL may be complaining about, such as apostrophes and for example `John's Bar & Grill`, then you will need to escape your data; something you should be doing in any event.

Sidenote: This `<input type="image"...` may also be failing you. Use a `type="submit"` as an input.

I.e.: `<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">`

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Displaying errors should only be done in staging, and never production.

---

Your present code is open to [**SQL injection**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/). Use [**`mysqli_*` with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO**](http://php.net/pdo) with [**prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements).

---

**Passwords**

I also noticed that you may be storing passwords in plain text. This is not recommended.

Use one of the following:

- [**CRYPT_BLOWFISH**](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/36471)
- [`crypt()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php)
- [`bcrypt()`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt)
- [`scrypt()`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrypt)
- [**On OPENWALL**](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/)
- [**PBKDF2**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2)
- [**PBKDF2 on PHP.net**](http://php.net/hash-pbkdf2)
- PHP 5.5's [`password_hash()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function.
- Compatibility pack (if PHP < 5.5) https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat/

Other links:

- [**PBKDF2 For PHP**](https://defuse.ca/php-pbkdf2.htm)

Comment: `
if(!empty($_POST['nickname']) && !empty($_POST['password']) )
        { $sql = "INSERT INTO UserDB (Name, Password) VALUES ('$nickname', '$pass')";
        ;}
        `
is it right?

Comment: @Jediah No, remove the `// Vloženie dát (Nick,` hold on, I'll make an edit for you to use.

Comment: @Jediah reload my answer and look under **Edit (example rewrite)**. that's how you can use it. and use an input type submit instead of an image button

Comment: @Jediah I tried that and that page doesn't exist `<form method="POST" action="login.php">` and I get a 404. So you need to fix that. I get redirected to http://error404.000webhost.com/? - that is LOGIN code, not for an INSERT. So, again, you need to use the right page/codes.

Comment: @Jediah what I suspect is going on here and that you failed to tell us is, you most likely have both your login and INSERT codes on the same page without a conditional statement. There isn't much else I can do for you here, but to say that you need to use either seperate pages/links, or use conditional statements for everything and based on what you want the user's action to be. Good luck with your project, I have done what I could here and won't be able to provide you with any further help on this.

Comment: <3 Thank you alot .. I´am starting to learn PHP so it was  a little big step for me :D Next time i will search for this type of errors. Can i give you somethink like a "karma" for solving problems? I just removed the ´action ="login.php"´ and it works nice now. :3